# I'm trying to send the base64 dataUrl as payload to the backend, but my function is returning an empty string

Tags: javascript, typescript, base64, data-uri

I'm developing a certificate designing application, and I want to send a base64 datUrl of the certificate to the backend. I wrote a "getThumbnail()" function in order to return a compressed base64 dataUrl of the certificate for preview.

```
getThumbnail(): string {
let node: any = document.getElementById('certificate-preview-container');
let thumbnail: string = "";

htmlToImage.toPng(node).then(function (dataUrl) {
    let img = new Image();
    img.src = dataUrl;
    document.body.appendChild(img);
    // console.log("DataUrl: ", dataUrl);
    console.log("DataUrl: ", typeof(dataUrl));
    //return dataUrl;
    img.onload = function() {
      // Create a canvas and draw the compressed image
      const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
      const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

      // Set the canvas dimensions to the desired size (e.g., for compression)
      canvas.width = img.width * 0.2; // Adjust the width as needed
      canvas.height = img.height * 0.2; // Adjust the height as needed

      // Draw the image onto the canvas
      ctx!.drawImage(img, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

      // Get the compressed data URL from the canvas
      const compressedDataURL = canvas.toDataURL('image/png', 0.5); // Adjust quality as needed

      // Display the compressed image
      const compressedImage = new Image();
      compressedImage.src = compressedDataURL;
      thumbnail = compressedDataURL;
      console.log("Thumbnail: ", typeof(thumbnail));
      //return thumbnail;
      document.body.appendChild(compressedImage);
      console.log("Compressed image: ", compressedDataURL);
      return thumbnail;
    }
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.error('oops, something went wrong!', error);
    //return thumbnail;
  });

  return thumbnail;
}
```

Then I wrote a "saveCertificate()" function which sends the required data as payload to the backend, which also includes the "thumbnail" field which is supposed to get the compressed base64 dataUrl.

```
saveCertificate(){

let data : CertificatePostBody = {
  certificate : {
    "id": Number(this.certificateId),
    "certificateTemplate": this.certificate.template,
    "height": this.certificate.height,
    "width": this.certificate.width,
    "backgroundImage": this.certificate.backgroundImage,
    "orientation": this.certificate.orientation,
    "certificateType": this.certificate.certificateType,
    "certificateName" : this.certificate.certificateName,
    "dateFormat" : this.certificate.date_format,
    "thumbnail" : this.getThumbnail()
    //"thumbnail": "test2"
  }
};
this.certificateService.updateCertificate(data).subscribe((res:any)=>{
  console.log('res=>', res);
  
})
```

The problem is that the "thumbnail" field shows blank when I check it in the network tab in inspect element, meaning the getThumbnail() function is returning a blank string. Now I am aware it could be because of the asynchronous nature of the htmlToImage.toPng function and it returns a promise. How can I modify the getThumbnail() function so that it returns the compressed dataUrl as string for me to send it to backend?

Comment: Why are you sending it as base64 anyway?  This adds ~33% overhead to the size, and wastes CPU and memory on both ends.

Comment: `getThumbnail()` needs to return the promise created by `htmlToImage.toPng(node)`. You would then need to await that result in `saveCertificate()` before using it in `data`

Comment: @Phil, how can I get the dataUrl string from the promise?

Comment: I already told you. There's also a link at the top of your post containing detailed information on how to return values from async calls